# mysql where linking table is either null or not equal to some id

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables; news and user_has_read

NEWS TABLE

```
news_id  title
1        happy days
2        war on the horizion
3        celebrity does something
```

USER HAS READ THE NEWS

```
news_id user_id date
1       1       jan 1
1       2       jan 2
2       1       jan 4
```

Basically I want to find all the stories that exist but that haven't been read or haven't been read by the particular user - so I can count notifications

So something like

```
SELECT 
news_id, 
title
FROM news
LEFT OUTER JOIN user_has_read ON
user_has_read.news_id = news.news_id
WHERE user_has_read.user_id IS NULL or user_has_read.user_id != 2
```

But this doesn't work for some reason, any ideas?

It should show that user_id (2 in this case) hasn't read 2 stories, but it doesn't

Is there a better way to go about this?

Comment: What is the result? Above query should return `first` & `third` rows from your `user_has_read` table right?

Comment: yeah it should but for some reason it returns all 3 @GGio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get those news that a particular user hasn't read, you've got to include the test of this user in the join condition of your outer join. Please regard that a news that's not read by anyone isn't read by this particular user too ...

```
SELECT
    n.news_id,
    un.user_id
FROM
    news n
LEFT JOIN
    user_has_read_the_news un
ON
    n.news_id = un.news_id AND un.user_id = 2
WHERE
    un.user_id IS NULL;
```

returns the news that the user with the `id = 2` hasn't read:

Result with your sample data:

```
news_id | user_id
-----------------
      2 | NULL
      3 | NULL
```

For the user_id of 1 the result will be

```
news_id | user_id
-----------------
      3 | NULL
```

For a user with an user_id of any other value as `1` or `2` the result will be of course all news:

```
news_id | user_id
-----------------
      1 | NULL
      2 | NULL
      3 | NULL
```

[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a315d/7)

Comment: A record that's not been read by anyone is not read by this particular user too. That's included.

Comment: @ShadowRadiance You should undelete your answer. The subselect is another way, maybe an more obvious one to the right result.

Answer (score 3):

The reason your query does not works is:

```
SELECT story_id, story_name 
FROM stories 
LEFT OUTER JOIN user_has_read.story_id = stories.story_id 
               ^ ON is missing
WHERE user_has_read.user_id IS NULL or != '$user_id'
                                      ^ syntax error since you are not specifying column
```

Change it to:

```
SELECT story_id, story_name 
FROM stories 
LEFT OUTER JOIN ON user_has_read.story_id = stories.story_id 
WHERE user_has_read.user_id IS NULL or user_has_read.user_id != '$user_id'
```

above assumes that you are properly getting the value of `$user_id` meaning its either in double quotes or you are using prepared statements.

Comment: thanks, I typed the query very quickly on the question, it's still not coming out correctly

Comment: There's a `ON` missing

Comment: The `ON` for a join condition is mandatory join syntax if the join condition exists.

Comment: yeah you're right I added ti in, I fixed it, im not getting an error on the query, it's just not giving me the right information

Comment: @PhilipYellen what is your `$user_id` then. Do a `var_dump`. Please provide more code including `php`

Comment: That worked perfectly, thank you so much, just saved me a few hours of scratching my head, really appreciate it

Comment: This is the code that worked :SELECT story_id, story_name 
FROM stories 
LEFT OUTER JOIN user_has_read ON user_has_read.story_id = stories.story_id  AND user_has_read.user_id = 2
WHERE user_has_read.user_id IS NULL

Comment: @PhilipYellen You should mark VMai's answer below as the answer since it contains the answer you chose.

Answer (score 1):

VMai's answer is correct. Leaving this here as we posted at the same time and the subselect is a different approach.

I'd change to:

```
SELECT news_id, title FROM news WHERE news_id NOT IN (
  SELECT news_id FROM user_has_read WHERE user_id=2)
```

That is "get rows from news, where news id not in (the news user 2 has read)".

I think another option might be:

```
SELECT news_id, title FROM news 
LEFT OUTER JOIN user_has_read ON (
  news.news_id= user_has_read.news_id AND 
  user_has_read.user_id=2)
WHERE user_id IS NULL
```